# Index error out of range while using xpath

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath, lxml

I have the error: list index out of range on the line `key = element.xpath('./@ID')[0]` using this code:

```
from lxml import etree
from urllib.request import urlopen


url = urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArthurK-GH/Instances/main/sprint01.xml')
doc = etree.parse(url)
root = doc.getroot()

DictShiftType= {}
DictDay = {}

pat = root.xpath('//Pattern')
for element in pat:
    key = element.xpath('./@ID')[0]
    shift = element.xpath('.//ShiftType/text()')
    day = element.xpath('.//Day/text()')
    DictShiftType[key]=shift
    DictDay[key]=day
```

But, if I copy/paste the part of the XML document I'm looking for, I read it using `fromstring` and copy/past the same lines of code it work as expected:

```
patterns = """
  <Patterns>
    <Pattern ID="0" weight="1">
      <PatternEntries>
        <PatternEntry index="0">
          <ShiftType>L</ShiftType>
          <Day>Any</Day>
        </PatternEntry>
        <PatternEntry index="1">
          <ShiftType>D</ShiftType>
          <Day>Any</Day>
        </PatternEntry>
      </PatternEntries>
    </Pattern>
    <Pattern ID="1" weight="1">
      <PatternEntries>
        <PatternEntry index="0">
          <ShiftType>D</ShiftType>
          <Day>Any</Day>
        </PatternEntry>
        <PatternEntry index="1">
          <ShiftType>E</ShiftType>
          <Day>Any</Day>
        </PatternEntry>
        <PatternEntry index="2">
          <ShiftType>D</ShiftType>
          <Day>Any</Day>
        </PatternEntry>
      </PatternEntries>
    </Pattern>
    <Pattern ID="2" weight="1">
      <PatternEntries>
        <PatternEntry index="0">
          <ShiftType>None</ShiftType>
          <Day>Friday</Day>
        </PatternEntry>
        <PatternEntry index="1">
          <ShiftType>Any</ShiftType>
          <Day>Saturday</Day>
        </PatternEntry>
        <PatternEntry index="2">
          <ShiftType>Any</ShiftType>
          <Day>Sunday</Day>
        </PatternEntry>
      </PatternEntries>
    </Pattern>
  </Patterns>
"""

doc = etree.fromstring(patterns)
DictShiftType= {}
DictDay = {}

pat = doc.xpath('//Pattern')
for element in pat:
    key = element.xpath('./@ID')[0]
    shift = element.xpath('.//ShiftType/text()')
    day = element.xpath('.//Day/text()')
    DictShiftType[key]=shift
    DictDay[key]=day
DictDay
```

output:

```
{'0': ['Any', 'Any'],
 '1': ['Any', 'Any', 'Any'],
 '2': ['Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']}
```

As I have to iterate through several sets of data I can't copy/paste the xml document in my code, so I tried to use `fromstring` at the begging of my code instead of `parse` but it doesn't work. Could you please help to figure out where is my mistake ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you analyse the xml structure, there are other taggs called Pattern that are causing the indexing error, because they don't have the `<Pattern ID="0" weight="1">`, see example:

```
<Pattern>0</Pattern>
<Pattern>1</Pattern>
<Pattern>2</Pattern>
```

If you just change the pat xpath to: `pat = root.xpath('//Patterns/Pattern')`, your code will work:

```
from lxml import etree
from urllib.request import urlopen


url = urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArthurK-GH/Instances/main/sprint01.xml')
doc = etree.parse(url)
root = doc.getroot()

DictShiftType= {}
DictDay = {}

pat = root.xpath('//Patterns/Pattern')
for element in pat:
    key = element.xpath('./@ID')[0]
    shift = element.xpath('.//ShiftType/text()')
    day = element.xpath('.//Day/text()')
    DictShiftType[key]=shift
    DictDay[key]=day
```

Output:

```
{'0': ['Any', 'Any'],
 '1': ['Any', 'Any', 'Any'],
 '2': ['Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']}
```